# Automatic start of a bundle in XPages OSGI runtime on Domino 9

Tags: xpages

Many sources noted that in Domino 8.5.4/9 should be clean way of starting OSGi bundles on HTTP startup as noted for example here http://lekkimworld.com/2011/07/08/dots_and_automatic_startup_of_bundles.html

Currently I'm still not able to find any documentation about it. Is there some extension point or other configuration that can be used for that?

In Domino 8.5.3 we did ugly hack when bundles pretend to be Dojo libraries and so they started automatically. On one of our Domino 9 test machines this probably causes troubles (every other restart server complains that No Dojo library could be found), so I wanted to cleanup our code.

Bundle is our workflow engine and since it can do some automatic processing we need to start it even when no request comes to server.

Answer (score 0):

The webdav plug-in on OpenNTF has an autostart option. In this case it was linked to the Servlet extension point. That might help. Are you extending Activiti?

Comment: Yes, in this case it was Activiti and few others tasks that we use for integration. At the end we used what extension point that was used by mindoo ftp server http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/03.11.2012141402KLEHJC.htm